# Как правильно обработать ошибку в vk_requests, python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, исключения

Хочу получить новые сообщения в вк.
Делаю это через getLongPollHistory. В офф. документации - 
Ошибки с кодами 907 и 908 означают, что нужно получить новое значение pts (''ts''') и вызвать метод повторно с новыми значениями, поскольку данных для переданных значений не существует.

И по идее оно должно возвращать в ответе поле error:

`"error": {
"error_code": 907,
"error_msg": "Value of ts or pts is too old",
"request_params": [{
"key": "oauth",
"value": "1"
}`

Но мне сама библиотека кидает исключение:`vk_requests.exceptions.VkAPIError: error_code=907,message='Value of ts or pts is too old',request_params={...}`

Окей, пытаюсь обработать его:

```
   try:
        msgs = vk_api.api.messages.getLongPollHistory(ts=self.ts, pts=123456) # 123456 - чтобы вызвать ошибку
        new_msg = False
        for event in msgs['history']:
            if event[0] == 4:  # если есть новое сообщение
                new_msg = True
        if new_msg:
            print(msgs['messages'])
            self.pts = msgs['new_pts']
    except vk_requests.exceptions.VkAPIError as vk_error:
        print(vk_error)
        print(vk_error.args)
        error_code, message, request_params = vk_error
```

Но не тут то было - если просто делать `print(vk_error)` - все ок, выдает `error_code=907,message='Value of ts or pts is too old',request_params={...}`
Но при попытки получить аргументы исключения ругается:

```
error_code, message, request_params = vk_error
TypeError: 'VkAPIError' object is not iterable
```

А `vk_error.args` вообще пустое...

Это я что-то не так делаю или там ошибка это просто строка и мне нужно всякими костылями error_code вытаскивать?

И еще такой вопрос - я вообще правильно делаю, что для получения новых сообщения просто раз в секунду эту функцию вызываю? Просто в моем понимании лонгпул не для того нужен, чтобы его раз в секунду запросами тыкали...

Comment: Не пробовали добавить проверку типа: `if error_code in msgs['error']: что-то делаем`

Comment: Пока что сделал if ('error_code=907' in vk_error) or ('error_code=908' in vk_error):
Но просто хотелось бы все аргументы ошибки нормально выводить, а чет не выходит...

Comment: киньте сюда содержимое dir(vk_error) и vk_error.__dict__

Comment: О, спасибо, я что-то через __dict__ не догадался.
error_code = vk_error.error_data['error_code'] -вот так получилось, через .error_data можно все поля получить.